# Update AND select in one statement (with 1 WHERE clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause

How can I simplify the following SQL statement to 1 `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabA 
WHERE (colCar IS NULL OR colCar = '') 
   OR (colBike IS NULL OR colBike = '') 
   OR (colTrain IS NULL OR colTrain = '')

UPDATE tabA 
SET Distance = 999 
WHERE (colCar IS NULL OR colCar = '') OR 
      (colBike IS NULL OR colBike = '') OR 
      (colTrain IS NULL OR colTrain = '')
```

This statement makes no sense, but it is working fine.

I just want avoid to use the `WHERE` clause twice.

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Mike

SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabA 
WHERE (colCar IS NULL OR colCar = '') 
   OR (colBike IS NULL OR colBike = '') 
   OR (colTrain IS NULL OR colTrain = '')

UPDATE tabA 
SET Distance = 999 
WHERE (colCar IS NULL OR colCar = '') 
   OR (colBike IS NULL OR colBike = '') 
   OR (colTrain IS NULL OR colTrain = '')
```

Code is working fine

Comment: I suspect the SELECT is just a preview or confirmation of the records to be updated.  CAUTION, and UPDATE with no WHERE will update all records.

Comment: Do you want like this:

`UPDATE t 
SET t.Distance = 999 
FROM tabA t
WHERE (t.colCar IS NULL OR t.colCar = '') 
   OR (t.colBike IS NULL OR t.colBike = '') 
   OR (t.colTrain IS NULL OR t.colTrain = '')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTPUT clause to return updated rows:

```
UPDATE tabA 
SET Distance = 999
OUTPUT deleted.colCar
     , inserted.colCar
     , deleted.colBike
     , inserted.Distance
WHERE (colCar IS NULL OR colCar = '') OR 
      (colBike IS NULL OR colBike = '') OR 
      (colTrain IS NULL OR colTrain = '')
```